# How can I match bootstrap column heights with pure jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there is a library called match-height.js that already does this for you but I'm trying to do it from scratch. I have row with 2 columns, the first one has a centered (horizontally and vertically) black square. The second column has a heading and a paragraph. I just want to match the heights of the columns with the class "about-wrapper".

HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="about-section">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 about-wrapper" id="about-logo-wrapper">
            <div id="about-logo"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 about-wrapper" id="about-text-wrapper">
            <h2 class="main-heading" id="about-heading"> ABOUT THE CEO </h2>
            <p class="main-body" id="about-body">
                Paragraph content goes here...
            </p>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#about-logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

#about-logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: black;
    margin: 0px auto;
    align-self: center;
}
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#about-logo-wrapper").height = $("#about-text-wrapper").height;
});
```

Comment: `$("#about-text-wrapper").height($(".about-wrapper").height());`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `height()` wrong.  It's a function, not a property, and it takes a parameter when you want to use it to set height...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#about-logo-wrapper").height($("#about-text-wrapper").height());
});
```

See the documentation for more info...

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first to check which height is greater: either left cell or right one:

```
var h = $("#about-text-wrapper").height() > $("#about-logo-wrapper").height() ? 
        $("#about-text-wrapper").height() : 
        $("#about-logo-wrapper").height();
```

then set this height to `about-wrapper`

```
$(".about-wrapper").height(h);
```

Look at snippet in full page mode:

```js
var h = $("#about-text-wrapper").height() > $("#about-logo-wrapper").height() ? $("#about-text-wrapper").height() : $("#about-logo-wrapper").height();

$(".about-wrapper").height(h);
```

```css
#about-logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

#about-logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: black;
    margin: 0px auto;
    align-self: center;
}
#about-text-wrapper {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="about-section">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 about-wrapper" id="about-logo-wrapper">
            <div id="about-logo"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 about-wrapper" id="about-text-wrapper">
            <h2 class="main-heading" id="about-heading"> ABOUT THE CEO </h2>
            <p class="main-body" id="about-body">
                Paragraph content goes here...
            </p>
           <h2 class="main-heading" id="about-heading"> ABOUT THE CEO </h2>
            <p class="main-body" id="about-body">
                Paragraph content goes here...
            </p>
           <h2 class="main-heading" id="about-heading"> ABOUT THE CEO </h2>
            <p class="main-body" id="about-body">
                Paragraph content goes here...
            </p>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
CSS:
```